# How do I get a field rendered with translated labels?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a node I render with the following code.

```
$render_controller = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder($node->getEntityTypeId());
$render_output = $render_controller->view($node);
echo \Drupal::service("renderer")->render($render_output);
```

The rendered field labels are always in the original language (for example, German), even if I use `$node->getTranslation("en")`.

I find it difficult to get translated labels to render properly. I've searched through the source code all the way from back to front to find an answer. I see my translated field label in the frontend under "/admin/config/regional/config-translation/node_fields" so it must be stored *somewhere*.

How do I access it or even better render the whole field correctly?

Neither `$field->getLabel()` nor `$language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language) helped. Somehow Drupal must think it's very clever and uses some default language I don't want. I want to pick a specific language and render that. I would expect that using`getTranslation()` on the node really gives you everything in the right language, but it doesn't happen. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You have the change the current config translation language. [user_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_mail/8.1.x) has an example for that:

```
  $language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager();

  $language = $language_manager->getLanguage('en');
  $original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);

  // Do your thing here.

  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($original_language);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Berdir. This is *exactly* what I'm doing. `$language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager(); $language = $language_manager->getLanguage('en');  $original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage(); $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language); $view = $myvalue->view("default"); echo strval(\Drupal::service("renderer")->render($view));  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($original_language);`

It doesn't work.